# auto-popup argument methods and attributes in writing a python function

Tags: python, ide

is there any python IDE that can do the following?

for example, when I define a new function

```
#x: a pandas DataFrame
def fun1(x):
  k=x.T
  ...
```

There can be a way to tell the IDE the class of x, so that when I type `x.` the IDE can popup all the attributes and methods of the class for me to select?

Comment: Most modern IDEs support Python's optional [type hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) for this purpose. But questions about tools are not really suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks so much, @kindall! I'm using spyder. After some googling, I cannot find any info of using type hints in spyder for the above purpose. Could you please give more details?

Comment: Maybe Spyder doesn't. I believe PyCharm does.